Ganesh and creation
I want to learn creation from maha ganapatis kathas. I have read this passage
"
The following story is written in Ganesha Upanishad.
In the beginning, there existed only silence and darkness. Suddenly, a great sound came into being. This sound grew louder and louder until it filled every corner of the Universe. Aum, aum, aum. All was lit with radiance as the figure of Ganesha emerged from the Universe (Brahman). The Lord had taken Form to create a new Universe after the previous one had been burnt by the heat of twelve suns (Mahapralaya).
Lord Ganesha then summoned the three great gods — Brahman, Vishnu and Mahesh and assigned to them the duties of creation, preservation and destruction respectively. “I am the Universe. All that exists in the past, present and future lies within me. Within me, you shall seek Truth and Knowledge,” saying so Lord Ganesha swallowed the three great gods.
Inside Lord Ganesha, the gods saw the very structure of the Universe — the fourteen worlds, the gods and demons, the gandharvas and the apsaras, the sages and the saints. And soon, they set about their work. Thus the world came into being."
And I want to learn more. Where can I find, please try provide english copy puran. Thanks ❤️ 

Check the book tantra unveiled(Pandit Rajmani). It says adya Shakti’s first creation is Ganesh baba. Compares him with gravitational energy.

https://vedantastudents.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Ganapati-Atharvashirsha-Upanishad.pdf

http://www.dharmicscriptures.org/Ganapati%20Upanishad%20with%20translation.pdf
